# unable to print the arraylist

Tags: java

I'm unable to print for the getLines method, am I doing something wrong here? It doesnt give me any errors when I run the program but when I try to print the getlines method, it gives me errors.

it gives me this erros when i try to print the getlines method. 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at dijkstra.Fileprocess.getLines(Fileprocess.java:37) at dijkstra.Fileprocess.main(Fileprocess.java:70)

```
     public class Fileprocess {


  public static Scanner Reader(String FileName){

      //Pass a File Name to this method, then will return Scanner for reading data from that file
         try {
            return new Scanner(new File(FileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
            return null;
        }
    }  
  static ArrayList<Edge> getLines(ArrayList<Vertex> PointCollection) {
        Scanner Input = Reader(Vertex.graph);
        ArrayList<Edge> result = new ArrayList<Edge>();

        while(Input.hasNext()){
            String line = Input.nextLine();

            String[] arr = line.split(" ");
            result.add(new Edge(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), //index
                    getPointbyIndex(PointCollection,Integer.parseInt(arr[1])), //start
                    getPointbyIndex(PointCollection,Integer.parseInt(arr[2])), //end
                    Integer.parseInt(arr[3]))); //cost
            }
        Input.close();
        return result;
    }

  static ArrayList<Vertex> getPoints() {
      Scanner Input = Reader(Vertex.airports);
      ArrayList<Vertex> result = new ArrayList<Vertex>();

      while(Input.hasNext()){
          String line = Input.nextLine();
          result.add(new Vertex(line));
      }
      Input.close();
      return result;
  }

  static Vertex getPointbyIndex(ArrayList<Vertex>PointCollection, int Index){
      for(Vertex p:PointCollection){
          if(p.getIndex() == Index){
              return p;
          }
      }
      return null;
  }

 public static void main(String[] args){
     System.out.println(getPoints());
     System.out.println(getLines(null));
     }


}
```

this is the file for the input text file(index,start,end,cost)

```
1 1 2 2
2 1 3 1
3 1 6 3
4 1 7 3
5 2 1 2
6 2 3 1
7 2 4 1
8 2 5 2
9 2 6 2
10 3 1 1
11 3 2 1
12 3 4 1


class Edge {

    public Vertex start;
    public Vertex end;
    public double cost;
    public int Index;

//  public final Vertex target;
//  public final int weight;


    public Edge(double cost, Vertex end, Vertex start, int Index){

        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.Index = Index;
    }
       public String toString(){
            String result = "";
            if(this.start != null && this.end != null){
                result = this.Index +","+this.start.Index+","+this.end.Index +","+this.cost;
            }
            return result;
        }


}
```

Comment: What is the problem? How can we help if you don't tell us what the problem is?

Comment: it gives me this erros when i try to print the getlines method.        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at dijkstra.Fileprocess.getLines(Fileprocess.java:37)
 at dijkstra.Fileprocess.main(Fileprocess.java:70)

Comment: Well then maybe you should put it in the question!

Comment: you need to check if your split array has the right length. if(arr.length == 3) etc.

Comment: which line is line 37?

Comment: line 37 is    getPointbyIndex(PointCollection,Integer.parseInt(arr[1])), //start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your file contains an empty or incompatible line?

you can fix the error using:

```
String[] arr = line.split(" ");
if (arr.length > 3) {
    result.add(new Edge(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), //index
            getPointbyIndex(PointCollection,Integer.parseInt(arr[1])), //start
            getPointbyIndex(PointCollection,Integer.parseInt(arr[2])), //end
            Integer.parseInt(arr[3]))); //cost
    }
}
```

Comment: there isnt any empty lines in the file, but it doesnt give me an errors now after i put in ur code, but can i ask what does the if (arr.length > 3) do???

Comment: You got the error because you tried to access an index in an array that doesn't have that index. Here you try to access array only if this index exists.

Comment: well doesnt give me an error now but im not sure how i can print out the file, can i use System.out.println(null);?

Comment: You dont need to change the println command. Do you see any errors?

Comment: you use System.out.println(getLines(null));?

Comment: yes, im guessing that isnt going to print anything out, but im not sure what can i put inside it to have the output

Comment: Are you sure you get the input file as needed? you can print all lines just to see if its right or not...

Comment: yes im sure is the correct input file as i have done the same to the other file. Um is there any other way i can print all the lines other than using system.out.println(null)??

Comment: Do not use system.out.println(null). Use  system.out.println(line) for example, if line is a string.